# New Android Face API limitations

Tags: android, face-detection, vision, google-vision

I have been testing the new Face API realesed for android, and noticed even with "ACCURATE_MODE" enabled, it doesn't detect faces that old FaceDetector API used to detect, Also i would like to know the effect of Bitmap coding "RGB_565" vs "ARGB_888" in producing the results.

Comment: Can you give some examples?  Is there anything in common with the examples that don't work for you? (e.g., very small faces?).

Comment: It seems to me that the face dimension has to be in a "proper ratio" compared to the image dimension to get detected. So the faces are not necessarily small to not get detected but they are small compared to the image size. If I crop the image in the runtime and pass it to the detector it will detect those faces and as much as I zoom in more (by cropping a smaller size of the original image) it will detect more faces in a case that I have multiple faces in the image.

Comment: Makes sense.  See the edits to my answer below, which explains this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The issue was that the face detector is set to only detect faces that are at least 10% by default (as a performance optimization).

The new Google Play Services 8.4 release supports setting this minimum face size lower, enabling smaller faces to be detected.  See the setMinFaceSize method here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector.Builder.html#setMinFaceSize(float)

Comment: I assume there's no way to manipulate those numbers, any suggestions on how to detect smaller faces in an image considering the fact that I don't necessarily know where in the image they are located and what ratio the face may have compared to the image size

Comment: Based on my experience width of the image is not the only factor and I had to slice in the height as well to detect most of the faces for example overlapping slices of 400x400.

Comment: See the update above, which allows smaller faces to be detected without the need for slices.

Comment: does the new release also include the safeDetector patch inside itself?

Comment: Yes, the new release includes this patch, so the SafeDetector is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same issue on our ObscuraCam[0] project, and are left using both the old and the new API to try and maximize detection.

It seems like the new API is only better in the details it gives you about the face landmarks and the expression classification, and not in the ability to actual detect faces or partial faces.

[0] https://github.com/guardianproject/obscuracam